# The value of $a$ for which $f(x)=x^3+3(a-7)x^2+3(a^2-9)x-1$ have a positive point of maximum

Tags: calculus

> The value of $a$ for which $f(x)=x^3+3(a-7)x^2+3(a^2-9)x-1$ have a
>   positive point of maximum lies in the interval
>   $(a_1,a_2)\cup(a_3,a_4)$.find the value of $a_2+11a_3+70a_4$

---

I found $f'(x)=3x^2+6(a-7)x+3(a^2-9)=0$ and Let the point of maximum is $x_1>0$
So $f''(x)=6x+6(a-7)<0$
$\implies 6x_1+6(a-7)<0$
But i am stuck here.The answer given in my book is $a_2+11a_3+70 a_4=320$.From this answer i cannot know what is the interval $(a_1,a_2)\cup(a_3,a_4)?$

Comment: I suggest you do more work yourself than presenting all your homework problems for others to solve.

Comment: @uniquesolution,please Sir.I am not presenting my homework problems.I have shown my try.I am not a student.I am a teacher of maths and i am upgrading my maths skills to teach advanced level courses.

Comment: Why downvote folks.I have shown my attempt.I tried my best.I hate posting questions.Posting question is my last resort.

Comment: Brahmagupta -- With all due respect, sir, I had a glance at some of your posts in the recent two years, and if I had to make an educated guess I'd say you are systematically using the eagerness of people to earn points so that your homework problems will be solved. You seldom, if ever, present an effort which is merely a little more than re-writing the problem, and to be honest, I find it incredible that you are a maths teacher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of maximum is the least root of $f'(x)=0$. In order for it to be positive, both roots must be. So we need, after writing the equation as
$$
x^2+2(a-7)x+(a^2-9)=0,
$$
that the following conditions are satisfied:
\begin{cases}
-2(a-7)>0           & \text{sum of roots is positive} \\
a^2-9>0             & \text{product of roots is positive} \\
4(a-7)^2-4(a^2-9)>0 & \text{discriminant is positive}
\end{cases}

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Could you explain why "the point of maxima is the least root of $f'(x)=0$?"

Comment: @Techie5879 You have a cubic with positive leading coefficient, so its limit at $-\infty$ is $-\infty$ and the function is increasing up to the first critical point, which is therefore a point of local maximum (it's not a point of inflection because the derivative has two distinct roots).

Comment: @egreg just a last followup, why does the derivative need to have two distinct roots?

Comment: @Techie5879 Well, you're right. We need positive discriminant. Actually, it was $>0$ in the inequality, but the comment is wrong.

Comment: @egreg What I'm asking is, you stated in your answer that D>0, ie the discriminant needs to be positive (which also means in other words that the equation needs to have two distinct real roots). I'm asking why is this the case?

Comment: @Techie5879 If the discriminant is $\le0$, the function is strictly increasing, so it has no local maximum. In a different way, at a local maximum the derivative must vanish, so the discriminant has to be $\ge0$, but it can't be $0$ or the function would be increasing.

Comment: @egreg Okay thanks, that cleared up that part for me. Also, why does the least root have to be the point of maximum? Why not the greater root ?

Comment: @Techie5879 I've already explained it in my first reply.